# returning article by id -- vue router, vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to return article ID and go the detail page for that id. I did something like below. But in the end it's not working... in the console there is an error popping up and pointing that:

> api/v1/article[object%20Object]:1 Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I need some help because I am a bit lost here... What I am missing here? what I do wrong?

**Vuex**

```
export const articles = {
    state: {
        article: {},
    },

    mutations: {
        setArticle(state, article){
            state.article = article;
        },
    },
    getters: {
        loadArticle(state){
            return state.article;
        },
    },
    actions: {
        getArticle(id){
            axios.get("api/v1/article" + id)
            .then(response => {
                this.commit('setArticles', response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);

            })
        },
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
{
    path: "detail/:id",
    name: "detail",
    component: Vue.component("Detail", require("./pages/Detail.vue").default),
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
    }
},
```

**Article Component**

```
export default {
    components: {
        maps,
    },
    data(){
        return {

        };
    },
    created(){
        this.$store.dispatch( 'getArticle', {
            id: this.$route.params.id
        });
    },
    computed: {
        article(){
            return this.$store.getters.loadArticle;
        }
    }
}
```

Link to the article id

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'detail', params: { id: item.id } }">詳細を見る</router-link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

First `parameter` to store action is the store properties itself. This is the reason you get the `store` object. You need to receive `id` or any payload as second parameter.

```
actions: {
        getArticle({ commit }, id){
            axios.get("api/v1/article" + id)
            .then(response => {
                commit('setArticles', response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);

            })
        },
    }
```

Here you see this

```
created(){
        this.$store.dispatch( 'getArticle', {
            id: this.$route.params.id
        });
    },
```

You are passing an `object` as parameter-

```
{
   id: this.$route.params.id
}
```

You should be doing this instead -

```
created(){
   this.$store.dispatch( 'getArticle', this.$route.params.id);
},
```

Comment: still same problem. it is saying that I am giving an object? hmm

Comment: Try to add logs  in your action and created hook. `console.log(id)` in action and `console.log(this.$route.params.id)` in created hook then share what you got in console of the browser.

Comment: console.log is returns the id there is no problem with that. And before you ask api is working without a problem i  see the json data of the id. The thing i don't understand even I go to "id" why ID is being object?

Comment: This way we can help only if you share the log  iside `getArticle(id)` . Can you share that `id` value logged in `getArticle(id)`

Comment: sure here it is the screen show of the console of the `getArticle(id)` https://imgur.com/a/iJxSkxo i `console.log(id)` and also if I `console.log(response.data)` then it's being empty...

Comment: oh you got it right!! now it s not returning an object. But one hell a problem. Now I can't return the getters.. it's being empty? in the end I will check this as a answer. But could you point it out why I can't return any data?

Comment: That will be a separate question - Understand - You don't need a getter IMO  - You have state you apply action and mutate it. States have watcher on it so the moment it get updated, wherever you using that state will get reflected

Comment: yes I guess I need a another question for that. because it's not working with usual way.